# Radio Button Showing as a Hyperlink?

Tags: html, css, radio-button, label

I have four radio buttons, and although they display correctly on desktop web browsers when I view them on the iOS simulator and iPhone they "size3" radio label displays as a hyperlink? Why is this or how can I correct the issue?

http://jsfiddle.net/jasonniebauer/eLMqk/

HTML

```
<div id="surv_radio3">
<p>
    Square Footage
</p>
<div>
    <input type="radio" id="size1" name="sqft"/>
        <label for="size1">
            0-250
        </label>
    <input type="radio" id="size2" name="sqft"/>
        <label for="size2">
            251-500
        </label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="radio" id="size3" name="sqft"/>
        <label for="size3">
            501-2000
        </label>
    <input type="radio" id="size4" name="sqft"/>
        <label for="size4">
            2000+
        </label>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#surv_radio3 > div:nth-of-type(1) input[type="radio"] + label,
#surv_radio3 > div:nth-of-type(2) input[type="radio"] + label {
            box-sizing:border-box;
            padding: 1rem 3rem 1rem 3rem;
            width: 100%;
            display: inline-block;
            color: #BDC3C7;
            background-color: #F2F2F2;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            cursor: pointer;
            border-radius: 3px;
            font-size: 1.125em;
            margin-bottom: .5rem;
        }

#surv_radio3 input[type="radio"] {
            display: none;
}
```